# ESP32 classic Bluetooth set password

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, esp32

I am using the ESP32 classic Bluetooth feature for data transfer.

I am using the SerialToSerialBT example.

I am able to scan and discover the Bluetooth device from my smartphone, but the pairing is without any security/passcode. It simply pairs immediately. How to make the pairing use PIN/passkey entry?

**Hardware:**
ESP32 DEV Kit V1

**Software**
Arduino IDE

**Code:**

```
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(5000);
  Serial.println("Starting..");
  SerialBT.begin("MyESP32"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
  
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: the BluetoothSerial header file has `bool setPin(const char *pin);` (PIN as personal identification number)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ESP32 doesn't have inbuilt password configuration mechanism. So your requirement may not be straightforward as there could also be a standard Android OS/IOS handshaking protocol between any password protected bluetooth device and the phone during connection, which you need to figure out.

Instead, why not try something simpler like this at application level?:

1. Connect the smart phone and ESP32 via bluetooth.
2. Send a request for password from ESP32.
3. Print this request in bluetooth terminal on phone, send back the password.
4. If the password is correct, flag this, and keep the connection for further communication, else disconnect from the phone using `serial.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

Answering a few months old question, because I'm feeling like it requires a bit more explanation.

As for now (Jan 2022) it's still not implemented in Arduino core for ESP32: https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/1458

BT offers a way to pair devices without PIN code called SSP (secure simple pairing). SDK for ESP32 (ESP-IDF) offers a way to disable this feature and use a legacy pairing (the one, which requires PIN code) only during compile time: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/2774

It's enabled by default and cannot be changed during the runtime. And because Arduino core for ESP32 uses ESP-IDF as the underlying SDK which is compiled with default options, including enabled SSP, it is not possible unless you modify & compile ESP-IDF by yourself.

As @MituRaj already suggested in other answer, other authentication methods can be used a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, downgrade arduino framework to 1.0.1 and replace `libbt.a` lib usually in `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.0\tools\sdk\lib`

Here is the link: [github](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2320#issuecomment-477288545)

There is also example demo.